# mathjs for integral functionality need help installing the specific npm

Tags: javascript, math, project, integral

Hello I have been trying to install the npm link for the math.integral function and I have been having trouble finding or using the script src to get this function.

I currently use the script src below for the math.js functions but I cant seem to have it work for the math.integral

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.0/math.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using npm / a module loader or pure JS with `<script>` tags? What exactly is the problem? What is your code?

Comment: I am using pure JS

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.1.0/math.min.js"></script>
<script src="../JS/calc/c1-2.js"></script>
</html>

Comment: Then your question has nothing to do with npm.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your actual code & problem.